# Drag And Drop как избавиться от дребезжания при заведении за пределы экрана

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Я не понимаю как реализовать логику того, чтобы не было дребезжания при заведении за пределы экрана.

`onMouseMove` срабатывает после того, как на блок кликнули и начали перетаскивать

```js
onMouseMove(event) {
    this.doNotGoBeyond();
    if (this.limitBool) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    const page = {
        x: event.pageX,
        y: event.pageY
    };
    this.move(page);
}
```

`doNotGoBeyond` - проверяет, достиг ли перетаскиваемый элемент границ игрового поля, т.е. если какие-то координаты стали больше, чем нужно, то перенести блок к краю экрана. Тут проблема в том, что когда я задаю координаты равные краю экрана, то при перетаскивании 0 не меньше 0 и блок можно перетащить и происходит дребезжание

```js
doNotGoBeyond() {
    this.limitBool = false;
    const bottom = this.heightGame - this.node.offsetTop - this.node.offsetHeight;
    const right = this.widthGame - this.node.offsetLeft - this.node.offsetWidth;
    if (this.node.offsetLeft < 0 || this.node.offsetTop < 0 || right < 0 || bottom < 0) {
        this.limitBool = true;
        if (this.node.offsetLeft < 0) {
            this.node.style.left = '0px';
        } else if (this.node.offsetTop < 0) {
            this.node.style.top = '0px';
        } else if (right < 0) {
            this.node.style.left = this.widthGame - this.node.offsetWidth + 'px';
        } else if (bottom < 0) {
            this.node.style.top = this.heightGame - this.node.offsetHeight + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

```js
class BlockInGame {
  constructor(src = 'move__block', styles) {
    this.global();
    this.node = document.createElement('div');
    this.node.classList.add(src);
    this.addStyles(styles);
    this.addInBody();
    this.listeners();
  }

  listeners() {
    this.node.ondragstart = () => {
      return false;
    }
    this.node.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
      this.shift = {
        x: event.clientX - this.node.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        y: event.clientY - this.node.getBoundingClientRect().top
      };
      const localMouseupFunc = () => {
        this.global.game.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMoveBind);
        this.global.game.removeEventListener('mouseup', localMouseupFunc);
      }
      const onMouseMoveBind = this.onMouseMove.bind(this);
      this.global.game.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMoveBind);
      this.global.game.addEventListener('mouseup', localMouseupFunc);
    });
    const heightAndWidthGame = this.heightAndWidthGame.bind(this);
    heightAndWidthGame();
    window.addEventListener('resize', heightAndWidthGame);
  }

  global() {
    if (!this.global.body) {
      this.global.body = document.querySelector('body');
    }
    if (!this.global.game) {
      this.global.game = this.global.body.querySelector('.game');
    }
  }

  heightAndWidthGame() {
    this.widthGame = this.global.game.offsetWidth;
    this.heightGame = this.global.game.offsetHeight;
  }

  addStyles(styles) {
    for (let key in styles) {
      this.node.style[key] = styles[key];
    }
  }

  addInBody() {
    this.global.game.append(this.node);
  }

  move(page) {
    this.node.style.left = page.x - this.shift.x + 'px';
    this.node.style.top = page.y - this.shift.y + 'px';
  }

  doNotGoBeyond() {
    this.limitBool = false;
    const bottom = this.heightGame - this.node.offsetTop - this.node.offsetHeight;
    const right = this.widthGame - this.node.offsetLeft - this.node.offsetWidth;
    if (this.node.offsetLeft < 0 || this.node.offsetTop < 0 || right < 0 || bottom < 0) {
      this.limitBool = true;
      if (this.node.offsetLeft < 0) {
        this.node.style.left = '0px';
      } else if (this.node.offsetTop < 0) {
        this.node.style.top = '0px';
      } else if (right < 0) {
        this.node.style.left = this.widthGame - this.node.offsetWidth + 'px';
      } else if (bottom < 0) {
        this.node.style.top = this.heightGame - this.node.offsetHeight + 'px';
      }
    }
  }

  onMouseMove(event) {
    this.doNotGoBeyond();
    if (this.limitBool) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    const page = {
      x: event.pageX,
      y: event.pageY
    };
    this.move(page);
  }
}
const block = new BlockInGame(undefined, {
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  width: '80px',
  height: '80px'
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

section {
  background-color: #00cbff;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.game {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.move__block {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="game">

</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чуть изменил Ваш код чтобы не переписывать много отвечая конкретно на вопрос, как избавиться от дребезжания. поправил метод `move` и `doNotGoBeyond`. дребезжание из-за того что Вы проверяете только значения меньше 0 а не равное ему. Такой эффект можете использовать не при движении, а при отпускании

```js
class BlockInGame {
  constructor(src = 'move__block', styles) {
    this.global();
    this.node = document.createElement('div');
    this.node.classList.add(src);
    this.addStyles(styles);
    this.addInBody();
    this.listeners();
  }

  listeners() {
    this.node.ondragstart = () => {
      return false;
    }
    this.node.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
      this.shift = {
        x: event.clientX - this.node.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        y: event.clientY - this.node.getBoundingClientRect().top
      };
      const localMouseupFunc = () => {
        this.global.game.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMoveBind);
        this.global.game.removeEventListener('mouseup', localMouseupFunc);
      }
      const onMouseMoveBind = this.onMouseMove.bind(this);
      this.global.game.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMoveBind);
      this.global.game.addEventListener('mouseup', localMouseupFunc);
    });
    const heightAndWidthGame = this.heightAndWidthGame.bind(this);
    heightAndWidthGame();
    window.addEventListener('resize', heightAndWidthGame);
  }

  global() {
    if (!this.global.body) {
      this.global.body = document.querySelector('body');
    }
    if (!this.global.game) {
      this.global.game = this.global.body.querySelector('.game');
    }
  }

  heightAndWidthGame() {
    this.widthGame = this.global.game.offsetWidth;
    this.heightGame = this.global.game.offsetHeight;
  }

  addStyles(styles) {
    for (let key in styles) {
      this.node.style[key] = styles[key];
    }
  }

  addInBody() {
    this.global.game.append(this.node);
  }

  move(page) {
    const pageX = page.x - this.shift.x; // Позиция мышки по X
    const pageY = page.y - this.shift.y; // Позиция мышки по Y
    if ((!this.limitBoolRight || (this.node.offsetLeft > pageX)) && pageX > 0) {
      // Если (не заходили справа за пределы ИЛИ позиция блока слева больше позиция мышки по X) И позиция мышки по X больше 0
      this.node.style.left = pageX + 'px';
    }
    if ((!this.limitBoolBottom || (this.node.offsetTop > pageY)) && pageY > 0) {
      // Если (не заходили снизу за пределы ИЛИ позиция блока сверху больше позиция мышки по Y) И позиция мышки по Y больше 0
      this.node.style.top = pageY + 'px';
    }
  }

  doNotGoBeyond() {
    this.limitBoolRight = false;
    this.limitBoolBottom = false;
    const bottom = this.heightGame - this.node.offsetTop - this.node.offsetHeight;
    const right = this.widthGame - this.node.offsetLeft - this.node.offsetWidth;
    if (right <= 0) { // Если зашли справа за пределы
      this.limitBoolRight = true;
      this.node.style.left = this.widthGame - this.node.offsetWidth + 'px';
    }
    if (bottom <= 0) { // Если зашли снизу за пределы
      this.limitBoolBottom = true;
      this.node.style.top = this.heightGame - this.node.offsetHeight + 'px';
    }
  }

  onMouseMove(event) {
    this.doNotGoBeyond();
    const page = {
      x: event.pageX,
      y: event.pageY
    };
    this.move(page);
  }
}
const block = new BlockInGame(undefined, {
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  width: '80px',
  height: '80px'
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

section {
  background-color: #00cbff;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.game {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.move__block {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="game">

</section>
```

Comment: что означает `pageX >= '0px'`? в pageX хранится строка же

Comment: @МихаилКамахин извиняюсь, там с числом должно быть сравнение, изменил ответ